Is it possible to add a non-floating, trailing supplementary view at the end of a horizontally scrolling compositional layout collection view?
I have a UICollectionView that uses compositional layout and a diffable data source. It functions similarly to the standard Netflix layout which is essentially a vertically scrolling list of sections, where each section contains a horizontally scrollable list.
It looks similar to this, where the black outline represents the screen area.

I would like to add 1 more static-content cell to the end of one of the horizontally scrolling lists, like this (static cell denoted at the end of section 1, in red):

If I weren't using diffable data source, I could just add another cell in the UICollectionViewDataSource methods. Since I cannot do that with diffable data source, I was hoping to add the red cell as a trailing supplementary view. However, when I attempt to do this, it just pins this supplementary view to the right side of the screen. What I actually want is for the supplementary view to appear at the end of the collection view cells, and scroll along with those cells. I know this can be done for a vertically scrolling section, where one would just add a non-sticky footer, but is it possible to accomplish a similar thing for a horizontally scrolling section?
